# Contextual Click and selecting the nth item

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I Have one question in selenium webdriver

I need to right click on say 10th item in the menu
1
2
.
.
10
Do i need to copy the same code 10 times
sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).....10
Is there any shortcut to click 10th item because the above code looks to be cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

it depends actually... if u can get the 10th web element directly, than u can right click on that directly but if this is like that u have to go to ur element by pressing down arrow key in a dropdown box, than just run a loop and inside the loop, call your method.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about how you identify the element, If lets say the element is directly identifiable you can click on that particular element and if the element isn't directly identifiable, in that case you have to keep on clicking the `DOWN_ARROW` then you can use something like below:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // Do your work (click or press DOWN_ARROW);
    // This way you can achieve it.
}
```